# How to implement a list of blocks in Optimizely CMS 12

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, episerver, optimizely

I am trying to implement a list of blocks in Optimizely CMS 12 as per these instructions: [List Properties](https://docs.developers.optimizely.com/content-cloud/v12.0.0-content-cloud/docs/property-value-list)

```
// Creating a contact block type
[ContentType(AvailableInEditMode = false, GUID = "38d57768-e09e-4da9-90df-54c73c61b270")]  
public class ContactBlock : BlockData  
{  
   //block properties  
}

// Trying to create a property (on another content type) that is a list of contact blocks
public virtual IList<ContactBlock> Contacts { get; set; }
```

However, when trying out this property in edit mode all I'm getting is a textarea.

Has someone made this work? The documentation even includes a screen shot of this functionality at work so I guess I am doing it wrong...

Comment: Hows your view snippet looks like? Could you please share few more details so that it can be reproduced accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: The view is not involved here. I am only trying to get the edit view to function as advertised (please see the link I provided).

Comment: Okay, thanks or your response, Let me check again.

Comment: Did you have a look at the rending part of the post. Are you using the propertyFor to get the on page edit? https://docs.developers.optimizely.com/content-cloud/v12.0.0-content-cloud/docs/property-value-list#rendering

Comment: this is released now in v 12.18 https://world.optimizely.com/documentation/Release-Notes/ReleaseNote/?releaseNoteId=CMS-25555

Answer (score 1):

I would stay away from this approach and instead either use `IList<ContentReference>` or a `ContentArea` (although the latter would require `ContactBlock` to be visible in edit mode), depending on your requirements.

Otherwise I would break out applicable properties from `ContactBlock` into a separate POCO class (i.e. without any `ContentType` attribute) and use that type for the `IList<T>` property.

I would then make `ContactBlock` inherit the POCO class (if you still need the block type for other uses).

However, if `ContactBlock` itself contains complex properties, you will likely need a custom serializer for your `IList<T>` type.

So, the easiest (and most future-proof) solution is one of the first two options.

Comment: Thanks! I see that Optimizely has updated the documentation and no longer shows the screenshot of the editing experience for IList<BlockType>. I think the solution(s) you suggested is the best way forward, but the documentation had me hoping. :)